# How to make Jackrabbit WebDAV servlet allow editing with Microsoft Word?

Tags: java, ms-word, webdav, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I'm trying to expose a Jackrabbit Oak repository through a servlet. While I'm able to successfully retrieve and edit a `.docx` file with LibreOffice Writer, Microsoft Word does not work.

**I'm making use of:**

- Jackrabbit Oak version 1.8.4
- Jackrabbit version 2.17.5
- LibreOffice Writer version 6.1.3.2

**The version of Word not working is:**

- Version 1708
- Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus.

I access the documents similarly in both editors by using the open document dialogue and putting in `http://localhost:8080/helloworld-singleton/repository/default/test.docx`

I've setup a simple servlet using the `OpenSecurityProvider` that exposes a repository that copies a local copy of a simple .docx document:

```
public class SimpleWebdavServlet extends SimpleWebdavServlet {
  private static Repository repository;

  public Repository getRepository() {
    return getRepositoryInternal();
  }

  static Repository getRepositoryInternal() {
    try {
      if (repository == null) {
        Jcr jcr = new Jcr().with(new OpenSecurityProvider());
        repository = jcr.createRepository();
        Session session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray()));

        Node rootNode = session.getRootNode();
        if (!rootNode.hasNode("test.docx")) {
          importFile(session, rootNode);
        }
        session.save();
      }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | RepositoryException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return repository;
  }

  private static void importFile(Session session, Node rootNode) throws FileNotFoundException, RepositoryException {
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test.docx"));
    ValueFactory valueFactory = session.getValueFactory();
    Binary contentValue = valueFactory.createBinary(is);
    Node fileNode = rootNode.addNode("test.docx", "nt:file");
    fileNode.addMixin("mix:referenceable");
    Node resNode = fileNode.addNode("jcr:content", "nt:resource");
    resNode.setProperty("jcr:mimeType", "application/octet-stream");
    resNode.setProperty("jcr:data", contentValue);
    Calendar lastModified = Calendar.getInstance();
    lastModified.setTimeInMillis(lastModified.getTimeInMillis());
    resNode.setProperty("jcr:lastModified", lastModified);
    session.save();
  }
}
```

This servlet is configured through the following `web.xml`:

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Jackrabbit Webdav</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Webdav</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.as.quickstarts.singleton.SimpleWebdavServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>resource-path-prefix</param-name>
      <param-value>/repository</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>missing-auth-mapping</param-name>
      <param-value>admin:admin</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>resource-config</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Webdav</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/repository/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

With this code, I would have expected that I would be able to open the document in Word, edit it, and save the changes to the server - Like I'm able to in LibreOffice Writer.

Instead with Word, the document is opened with protected view, attempt to save changes, you're only prompted to save a local copy of it.

I've tried to make a similar servlet for another JCR Implementation ModeShape, and experienced no problems with the persisting documents through Word there.

As a possible explanation while debugging internally within Jackrabbit, a noticeable difference between the editors is that LibreOffice Writer sends over `null` in the `Authorization` header, while Word sends `Bearer` in the `Authorization` header for several of it's requests. All of these requests are then ignored due to the exception of `org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.DavException: Unable to decode authorization.`

Does anybody know why Word does not work as expected in this case?

Comment: FWIW, but not related to your issue: don't use unstable Jackrabbit versions (2.17 == odd == unstable) in production code.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that "Authorization: Bearer" is not supported in jackrabbit-jcr-server. The BasicCredentialsProvider class only supports "login:password" base64 encoded basic authentication.

For testing purposes, I modified the getCredentials() method to force basic authentication with "admin/admin" when bearer authorization is received:

```
...
if (authStr.length >= 2 && authStr[0].equalsIgnoreCase(HttpServletRequest.BASIC_AUTH)) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Base64.decode(authStr[1].toCharArray(), out);
    String decAuthStr = out.toString("ISO-8859-1");
    int pos = decAuthStr.indexOf(':');
    String userid = decAuthStr.substring(0, pos);
    String passwd = decAuthStr.substring(pos + 1);
    return new SimpleCredentials(userid, passwd.toCharArray());
} else if (authStr.length >= 1 && authStr[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Bearer")) {
    return new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray());
}
throw new ServletException("Unable to decode authorization.");
...
```

After that I recompiled the jackrabbit-jcr-server (using maven) and redeployed it, and then the direct edition with MS Word worked.

Now a better implementation should be done...

Comment: Hello, you can override the implementation of CredentialsProvider in your project so there is no need to change Jackrabbit source.

I was able to do that  but I cannot really open the Word document, did you succeed in opening/editing directly with Word?